# does anonymous inner class uses extends and implements keyword internally

Tags: java

I am new to java while reading i came across this anonymous inner class as far as i have been able to figure out (correct me if i am wrong) that anonymous class are sublclass of any class or it implement interface and create instance of a class at the same time.

### my question is

1. do anonymous inner class uses extend and implement keyword internally
2. if not then how it implements an interface or extends any class

---

CONSIDER FOLLOWING CODE

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    // do something.
}});
```

Comment: Since there is no class declaration, there's no line with which to state implements or extends. It is implied that the new anonymous class implements or extends the type it creates.

Comment: "anonymous class are sublclass of any class" - can *any* class  subclass every class ? No. "or it implement interface and instance of a class at the same time." - this part of the sentence doesn't make any sense to me. Your question is not clear!

Comment: i have already mentioned "correct me if  i am wrong" @alfasin

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Java Language Specification (JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5)),

> An anonymous class declaration is automatically derived from a class instance creation expression by the Java compiler.

This is all I could find in the JLS on this matter.

Comment: There's also [15.9.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1) *"If T denotes an interface, then an anonymous direct subclass of Object that implements the interface named by T is declared."* Not that it would shine any light on whether *keywords* are used internally - that would be an implementation detail.